# Chrome's spinning wheel does not stop spinning with a <link media="...">

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm using a CSS file for adaptations for mobile devices:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="v2-sites-mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 767px)" />
```

On a mobile device (width lower than 768 pixels), this works perfectly. On desktop devices however, when the file `sites-mobile.css` should not be loaded, Google Chrome lists it as 'Pending' in the 'Network' tab of the inspector:

[image]

As you can see, Chrome considers the file as 'not yet loaded'. This makes the spinning wheel spin infinitely:

[image]

Is this a bug in Chrome, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers will still download a stylesheet even if the media query does not currently match.

I will admit I hadn't seen the spinning wheel in Chrome under this circumstance. Have you tried it in other desktop browsers too?

Comment: It only happens in Chrome. It can download the stylesheet, but it should not show a spinning wheel infinitely.

Comment: If you start a new page with the link tag and no other markup does it still behave this way in Chrome?